# AngularJs $watchGroup - which expression in the group was last changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-watch

Using `$watchGroup`, how can I determine which expression in the group was changed

```
    $scope.$watchGroup(['dec','bin','oct','hex'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
       last_changed = ??? //return which exp was changed in this run...
       if(last_changed=='dec') //then something
       if(last_changed=='bin') //then something
       if(last_changed=='oct') //then something
       if(last_changed=='hex') //then something
    });
```

Edit 1:-

--->the problem is i can't unbind the n_vals from the newValues.

```
var n_vals = [];
 $scope.$watchGroup(['dec','bin','oct','hex'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
  last_updated = changed_one(newValues,n_vals); //last_updated EXP
    n_vals = newValues;
 });
```

## Solution:-

```
n_vals = angular.copy(newValues);
```

look the following link:
[Deep copying objects in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360401/deep-copying-objects-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular offers [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup) **(since 1.3)**.

Basically, it returns the scope variable `oldValue` and `newValue` in the manner how we put it in `watchGroup`.

Use the index of the scope variable to get its respective `newVal` and `oldVal` like below.

To get `newValue`s of respective scope variables:

```
newValue[0] // returns new value of dec
newValue[1] // returns new value of bin
newValue[2] // returns new value of oct
newValue[3] // returns new value of hex
```

To get `oldValue`s of respective scope variables:

```
oldValue[0] // returns old value of dec
oldValue[1] // returns old value of bin
oldValue[2] // returns old value of oct
oldValue[3] // returns old value of hex
```

```js
$scope.$watchGroup(['dec','bin','oct','hex'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    console.log(newValues[index]); //put index value as 0(dec), 1(bin), 2(oct) or 3(hex)
    console.log(oldValues[index]); //put index value as 0(dec), 1(bin), 2(oct) or 3(hex)
});
```

> **NOTE:**
>   Below logic is considering that only one value will change at a time.

**Edit 1**

To catch which variable was updated last, you can try below code.

```
var arrayOfValues = ['dec', 'bin', 'oct', 'hex'];
$scope.$watchGroup(arrayOfValues, function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    let last_changed;

    var chanedIndex = newValues.findIndex(function(val, key){
        return val !== oldValues[key];
    });

    last_changed = arrayOfValues[chanedIndex];

    // above logic could simply avoid the below conditional logic (refer 
    // comment above in front of if condition)
    if (angular.isDefined(last_changed)) {
        // your logic will come here as per your question
        switch(last_changed){
           case 'dec':
               doSomething();
           case 'bin':
               doSomething();
           case 'oct':
               doSomething();
           case 'hex':
               doSomething();
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit 2:**

I have minified the code and made the

```
var arrayOfValues = ['dec', 'bin', 'oct', 'hex'];
// generic method which will tell you which variable has been updated
$scope.checkWhichVariableHasUpdated = fucntion(watchGroupList, newValuesObj, oldValuesObj) {
    let _lastUpdatedValue;
    angular.forEach(watchGroupList, function(value, index) {
        if (newValuesObj[index] != oldValuesObj[index])
            _lastUpdatedValue = value;
    });
    return _lastUpdatedValue;
};

$scope.mySwitchFunction = function(changedVariable) {
    switch (changedVariable) {
        case 'dec':
            doSomething();
            break;
        case 'bin':
            doSomething();
            break;
        case 'oct':
            doSomething();
            break;
        case 'hex':
            doSomething();
            break;
    }

};

$scope.$watchGroup(arrayOfValues, function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    var last_changed = $scope.checkWhichVariableHasUpdated(arrayOfValues, newValues, oldValues);
    if (angular.isDefined(last_changed)) {
        $scope.mySwitchFunction(last_changed)
    }
});
```

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: @AhmedBadawy i updated my answer..hoping now it should clear your doubts

Comment: thanks very much for your effort. but the above code can be easily broken if i fill the arrayOfValues in a reverse order.

Comment: sorry! what if i changed the value of (dec) after (hex). that will output (hex) as the last changed value although that isn't true

Comment: sorry! didn't see it. is there any other way to do $watchGroup instead of creating a $watch for every elem.

Comment: i can copy the new array outside then compare it in the next run with the new newValues to spot the different values. but i can't unbind the n_vals variable value from the original newValues.
look for the edit in the question.

Comment: Thanks. found the answer. i will mark your answer as accepted.
i will put the answer after the question.

Comment: @AhmedBadawy Thanks. Glad to help you..:)instead of adding answer in question, you can edit my answer and put the changed code here itself.