# Why does pushing object to array override/update existing and alike object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My javascript/angular code is performing contrary to what i expect and i can't figure out why. I have an angular service defining two methods for getting and setting items

```
app.factory('orderItems',['Restangular','$mdDialog',function(Restangular,$mdDialog){
    var orderItems = [];

    return{
        getOrderItems: function(){
            return orderItems
        },


        setOrderItems: function(item,fillings){
            ...
            orderItems.push(item)
            ...

        }, ...
```

Items are set using `ng-click` and passing an item and checked addons;
`product_template.html`

```
<div >

    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="showAddons($event,product)">Add to Cart</md-button>

    </div>
```

`controller`

```
app.controller('productCtrl',['$scope','getProducts','orderItems','Restangular','$mdDialog',function($scope,getProducts,orderItems,Restangular,$mdDialog){
    //$scope.products;
    $scope.products = getProducts(Restangular);

    // Dialog
    $scope.showAddons=function(ev,product){
    $mdDialog.show({
        locals:{current_Product: product,},
        //inline controller
        controller:['$scope','current_Product','orderItems',function($scope,current_Product,orderItems){
        $scope.product = current_Product;
        $scope.addons = {
        checked:[],}
        ...
        }],
        templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
        targetEvent: ev, 
    })
    }

}])
```

`dialog.html`

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="addon in product.productAddons">
...
<md-checkbox class="md-secondary" checklist-model="addons.checked" checklist-value="addon"></md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
  <md-button class="md-raised" style="background-color:#f44336; color:#fff" ng-click="setOrderItems(product,addons.checked)">Done</md-button>
```

The problem arises when `setOrderItems` is passed a similar object more than once. The first time around, orderItems.push works as expected then when a similar product is passed to 'setOrderItems', it is pushed to 'orderItems' but all items in 'orderItems' are updated to this currently set item.

That is, if `orderItems` was`[{name:"chicken burrito",fillings:[{name:"cabbage"},{name:"cheese"}],...}]` before, after setting a similar item but with diff fillings, `orderItems` is updated to `[{name:"chicken burrito",filling:[{name:"guac"}],...},{name:"chicken burrito",filling:[{name:"guac"}],...}]` . If `setOrderItems` is passed a different product say `[{name:"goat burrito",...}]` it is added as expected.

Can't happen to find a similar issue around. What am i doing wrong. I want to be able to add similar items but with different fillings to `orderItems`.

Comment: The obvious answer is that you aren't pushing a *new* object, you are pushing the *same* object into the array twice. What you probably need to do is, after pushing an object onto the array, create a *new* object to replace it in the current scope.

Comment: @Matt, do you think could explain yourself in a complete answer, my JavaScript is not good. I would appreciate a good explanation if its no bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to see exactly with the code you've given. But if I'm following what you are doing correctly, then the problem is probably here:

```
$scope.products = getProducts(Restangular);
```

you are getting a set of products, I assume that there is an object for `chicken burrito` and an object for `goat burrito`. The problem, *I think*, is that you are using the same object for *every* chicken burrito. So when you push it onto the array you are pushing a reference to the object in `products`, you then edit that object and push it again. But again you are pushing a reference to *the same object*. If you actually look at your array before the second push, I suspect you will see that the object already on the array is already altered to match the one you are about to push because *it's the same object*.

To solve this, you need to make a copy of the object. To do that, take a look at this question:

[Deep copying objects in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360401/deep-copying-objects-in-angular)

`angular.copy` should let you copy your `product` so that you aren't always pushing the *same object*.

For example, you could do this:

```
setOrderItems: function(item,fillings){
    ...
    var itemCopy = angular.copy(item);
    orderItems.push(itemCopy);
    ...
}
```

Now you are always pushing a *copy* into your array and your array will fill with *independent* objects.